# Зависает программа при запуске не из idle

Tags: python, многопоточность

У меня игра 5 в ряд по локальной сети на python 3. Есть файл, запускающий сервер и файл, запускающий клиент.

Программа при запуске через idle ведет себя как и задумано.
Но при запуске двойным щелчком мыши из проводника программа зависает.
Это появилось после разделения программы на потоки, где один поток отвечает за обработку сетевого кода и игры, второй - за отрисовку окна.

Comment: Придется исправлять программу.

Answer (score 0):

В idle обработчик событий окна (Tk) уже запущен и новый просто игнорируется. Запуская из файла обработчик событий( `mainloop()` ) создается новый. В Вашем коде его создание заблокировано логикой другого потока или Вы его вообще не добавили.